# How do SOAP headers work in ASMX Web Services?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I have a project that uses an asmx file with [WebMethods] and [SoapHeader("Auth")]. I have no experience using SOAP and don't understand how it works yet.

Going through the code I noticed that you can use a variable with the same name as the header and it contains the data. How is the data sent to the header? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data comes from XML within the `<soap:Header>` section of the SOAP envelope.

Comment: So something is sending a SOAP request and that attribute grabs the header? Is that correct?

Comment: More or less. There may be more than one header. Only the matching header will be grabbed.

Answer (score 2):

The data is sent in header by making use of a class that derives from SoapHeader. This class will be declared as a property in your webservice class. Then in your web method you will check the authentication information in this property before processing the actual method.

A simple implementation can be found here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/authforwebservices.aspx

The following msdn link tells about another similar technique, which would be more sophisticated one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z52by6a.aspx.

Basic idea behind passing data in header remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for your soap header like normal.

```
public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string CompanyID;
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
}
```

Then within your normal class had the reference.

```
public class MyClass : WebService
{
    public readonly AuthHeader authHeader;

    [SoapHeader("authHeader", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
    [WebMethod(CacheDuration = 20
        , EnableSession = true
        , Description = "Find stuff now."
        , MessageName = "FindStuff")]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false
        , ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml
        , XmlSerializeString = true)]

    public MyResponseClass FindStuff(string searchString)
    {
        MyResponseClass myResponseClass = new MyResponseClass();
        if (authHeader.Username == "myUser" &&
            authHeader.Password == "myPass" &&
            authHeader.CompanyID == "BobsTire")
        {
            ....
            myResponseClass = ....
        }
        return myResponseClass;
    }
}
```